# How to use GIF image as ProgressBar?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar, android-glide

GIF image not visible again when it's gone on button click event. It works for the first time but not work on button click event;

I load a GIF in image view using the below code;

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.loading_progress).asGif().into(ImgV);
```

GIF gone code is below;

```
ImgV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Again GIF is not visible on button click event using below code;

```
ImgV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I think you have to reassign the Gif to Imageview on making it visible again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Decision**
Load gif again with

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.loading_progress).asGif().into(ImgV);
```

after that change visibility

`ImgV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

**Second decision**
Just try to call

`ImgV.invalidate()`

Comment: when can i call ImgV.invalidate() ?

Comment: after you change visibility try to call invalidate()

Comment: doesn't work for me Cannot resolve method 'asGif' in 'RequestBuilder'!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Library to Show and Hide GIF on Button Click [GIF Drawable](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1147)

In your build gradle add these:

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }


}
    dependencies {
        implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
    }
```

In your Xml file:

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:id="@+id/gif"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/tenor"
    />
```

Then in you Java file

```
    GifImageView gifImageView = findViewById(R.id.gif);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (gifImageView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                gifImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                gifImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });
```